# Best design pattern for linking Api results together

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Language to use: C#

I have a situation where I have around 4/5 api calls to make but they are all dependent on the previous API call being successful.

For example:

1. CommandA
2. CommandB(Uses Result of CommandA)
3. CommandC(Uses Result of CommandB)

and so on and so forth - it really as simple as that. I have bneen recommended the builder pattern, Chain of responsibility and command pattern but don't know which one would be the easiest to build upon if i have to add any more commands later on down the line. Thanks.

For more context, I am trying to create a spotify playlist generator that takes in multiple different sources.

I currently have it set up so it has 2 flows - random songs and setlist fm songs.

the flow of the random songs is

- Check if playlist exists(create if not) (CommandA)
- Remove songs in playlist if specified(CommandB)
- Get Random Songs (CommandC)
- Add songs (CommandD)

and the flow for setlist fm is
 - CommandA
 - CommandB
 - Scrap setlist fm for songs
 - CommandD

here is an example code snippet:

```
    public ResponseCode GeneratePlaylistWithSongs(string playlistID, List<string> trackList)
    {
        PlaylistValidationResponseMessage playlistValidationRM = ValidatePlaylist(playlistID) as PlaylistValidationResponseMessage;
        if(playlistValidationRM.ResponseCode == ResponseCode.SUCCESS)
        {
            SongGetResponseMessage songGetResponseMessage = GetSongTracks(trackList) as SongGetResponseMessage;
            if(songGetResponseMessage.ResponseCode == ResponseCode.SUCCESS)
            {
                GeneratePlaylistResponseMessage generatePlaylistRM =
                    GeneratePlaylist(playlistID,
                    SourceType.SETLISTFM,
                    songGetResponseMessage.Track)
                    as GeneratePlaylistResponseMessage;

                return generatePlaylistRM.ResponseCode;
            }
        }
        return ResponseCode.FAILURE;
    }
```

as you can see, if i wanted to add any more to this flow i would just create a lot of if-elses on the response messages.

Comment: Not all tasks require a design pattern if it is exactly as you say then this just sounds like a sequence of statements (probably organized in a procedure or function)

Comment: I get what you are saying but i don't really want to have to do if-else statements to check if commandA has run successfully so now run command B etc.. @Hogan

Comment: Why not?  It sounds to me like that is what requirements specify.  No "pattern" is going to change having to do some if then else statement.  Unless there is something I'm missing here?  Maybe there is more than 3 steps?

Comment: Are you talking about "fluent" pattern?
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/fluent-code-in-c/

Comment: @Hogan added more context to the post

Comment: The builder pattern is a creational pattern, so I would say that one doesn't fit your scenario. The other two seem like overkill for your 'simple as that' problem. If you really want to use a pattern, the *Template* pattern is simple and can be refactored later. But I agree with @Hogan, if one part is dependent on the previous then you will have to do some form of checking to ensure you have the information you need for the next step(s).

Comment: @quaabaam I didn't make it clear, I am aware I will have to do checks but what pattern would allow the easiest way of linking these commands together without doing a lot of if-elses but also allowing me to pass the result of the previous command to the next.

Comment: so I guess this is chain of repsonsibility - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_patte - but honestly - this code looks fine.  If I did a code review where someone made this more complicated I would make them re-write it.

Comment: @Hogan okay fair enough, maybe I am thinking i've over engineered it in my head.

Comment: This is turning into an echo chamber! To echo what has been said by others, I really don't think you need a pattern. If you don't want a whole bunch of nested if-then's (which I agree is ugly) then you can just stack your if-then's, with a "return' if the result is not what's expected.

Comment: yeah -- if you get to the point where you have 500 to 1000 lines of "if else" constructs -- then make a chain of responsibility. Short of that make something that easy for others to maintain and read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced situations exactly like this... where I've had about 15 calls to make, but each call depended on the call before it being successful.  Here's how I handle it.

First, I created a `Response` object:

```
public class CallResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; } // this can vary based on  your needs
    public Exception ex { get; set; } // used only if there was an error in the call
}
```

Then, each call would return an instance of `CallResponse`:

```
    CallResponse response1 = Call1();
    if (!response1.Success) 
    {
        HandleError(response1)
        return;
    }

    CallResponse response2 = Call2(response1.Json);
    if (!response2.Success) 
    {
        HandleError(response2)
        return;
    }
```

And so on. I don't know if this fits a known pattern, but at least it keeps the top level code clean and easy to follow.

**EDIT:**

At the very least, you could avoid nesting your if-then's:

```
    public ResponseCode GeneratePlaylistWithSongs(string playlistID, List<string> trackList)
    {
        PlaylistValidationResponseMessage playlistValidationRM = ValidatePlaylist(playlistID) as PlaylistValidationResponseMessage;
        if(playlistValidationRM.ResponseCode != ResponseCode.SUCCESS)
        {
            return ResponseCode.FAILURE; 
        }

        SongGetResponseMessage songGetResponseMessage = GetSongTracks(trackList) as SongGetResponseMessage;
        if(songGetResponseMessage.ResponseCode != ResponseCode.SUCCESS)
        {
             return ResponseCode.FAILURE;
        }

        GeneratePlaylistResponseMessage generatePlaylistRM = GeneratePlaylist(playlistID, SourceType.SETLISTFM, songGetResponseMessage.Track) as GeneratePlaylistResponseMessage;
        return generatePlaylistRM.ResponseCode;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the best approach for me currently. I guess I had a "big brain" moment nesting it all.. this is much cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an oversimplified answer but you can build a fluent API that allows you to do something like this...

```
var response = new PlayListHandler()
    .DoCommandA()
    .DoCommandB()
    .DoCommandC(); 

return MyResponseGenerator.Translate(response);
```

Notes:

- PlayListHandler should implement an IPlayListHandler. Each "DoCommandX()" returns an IPlayListHandler.
- Each command should throw an exception if it returns a failed status code. You should be handling exceptions through [exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#exception-filters), allowing you to remove copy/pasted exception handling from your API method code.